# Excel::Writer::XLSX and "Read-Only" flag?

Tags: excel, xlsx, writer

I'm trying to find a way to get Excel::Writer::XLSX to write a spreadsheet that will prompt the user to open it Read-Only. In the way MS Excel can when Save As.. Tools, General,  Options is used.

[Excel prompting user on file open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTTU6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was added recently in Excel::Writer::XLSX 1.08 via the the workbook `read_only_recommended()` method: [Changes file](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Excel-Writer-XLSX).